# QMetaMethod::invoke() with argument defaults

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qmetaobject, qt-slot

When calling `QMetaMethod::invoke()` on a method that contains default arguments, the invoke fails.

```
class MyClass : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Q_INVOKABLE MyClass() : QObject(nullptr){}

public slots:
    int MyMethod(int a = 0)
    {
        return a*2;
    }
};


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    MyClass* object = new MyClass();
    QMetaObject *metaObject = object->metaObject();

    for(int i=metaObject->methodOffset(); i<metaObject->methodCount(); i++)
    {
        if(metaObject->method(i).name() == "MyMethod")
        {
            int returnVal;

            //returns false
            metaObject->method(i).invoke(object,
                                         Qt::DirectConnection,
                                         Q_RETURN_ARG(int, returnVal));

            break;
        }
    }

    return a.exec();
}
```

If I pass an int as the first argument, then it runs fine. Is there any way to retrieve the default values of the arguments for the method so that way I can pass those instead of passing nothing?

I was about to manually store the defaults within the class for each method, but this is an ugly hack.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: It returns false once, the other time it returns true. What's the problem? You want it to succeed once, and it's precisely what your code does... Other nitpicks: you don't need an invokable constructor, and even if you did, you should have `Q_INVOKABLE MyClass() = default;` - no need to explicitly initialize the base class with a defaulted argument. You also don't need a `QCoreApplication` instance, nor `a.exec()`, nor dynamic allocation: `MyClass object; auto *metaObject = object.metaObject();`

Comment: This was a code snippet. My real project returns on the first matching method name, requires constructor invoking because it is called from a script, and has a non QObject base class. QCoreApplication is the default for Qt console  projects. No one likes a nitpicker. You knew the focus of my question....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you review the generated .moc you see the following:

```
void MyClass::qt_static_metacall(QObject *_o, QMetaObject::Call _c, int _id, void **_a)
{
    if (_c == QMetaObject::InvokeMetaMethod) {
        MyClass *_t = static_cast<MyClass *>(_o);
        Q_UNUSED(_t)
        switch (_id) {
        case 0: { int _r = _t->MyMethod((*reinterpret_cast< int(*)>(_a[1])));
            if (_a[0]) *reinterpret_cast< int*>(_a[0]) = std::move(_r); }  break;
        case 1: { int _r = _t->MyMethod();
            if (_a[0]) *reinterpret_cast< int*>(_a[0]) = std::move(_r); }  break;
        default: ;
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see there are 2 methods generated and that can be verified by printing the methods with that name:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QMetaMethod>
#include <QDebug>

class MyClass: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    using QObject::QObject;
public slots:
    int MyMethod(int a = 0){ return a*2;}
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    MyClass object;
    const QMetaObject *metaObject = object.metaObject();
    for(int i=metaObject->methodOffset(); i<metaObject->methodCount(); i++)
    {
        QMetaMethod method = metaObject->method(i);
        if(method.name() == QByteArray("MyMethod"))
            qDebug()<<i<<method.name();
    };
    return 0;
}

#include "main.moc"
```

Output:

```
5 "MyMethod"
6 "MyMethod"
```

So what sets them apart? The number of parameters, so you must add a filter that is the [`parameterCount()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetamethod.html#parameterCount).

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QMetaMethod>
#include <QDebug>

class MyClass: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    using QObject::QObject;
public slots:
    int MyMethod(int a = 0){ return a*2;}
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    MyClass object;
    const QMetaObject *metaObject = object.metaObject();
    for(int i=metaObject->methodOffset(); i<metaObject->methodCount(); i++)
    {
        QMetaMethod method = metaObject->method(i);
        if(method.name() == QByteArray("MyMethod") && method.parameterCount() == 0)
        {
            int returnVal;
            bool status = method.invoke(&object,
                                        Qt::DirectConnection,
                                        Q_RETURN_ARG(int, returnVal));
            Q_ASSERT(status);
            qDebug()<<returnVal;
        }
    };
    return 0;
}

#include "main.moc"
```

Output:

```
0
```

On the other hand if you want to avoid this kind of problems you can use `QMetaObject::invokeMethod()` that makes that verification:

```
MyClass object;
int returnVal;
bool status = QMetaObject::invokeMethod(&object,
                                        "MyMethod",
                                        Qt::DirectConnection,
                                        Q_RETURN_ARG(int, returnVal));
Q_ASSERT(status);
qDebug()<<returnVal;
```

Comment: Great! Thanks so much for this. I guess this also explains overloaded functions as well. :)

Comment: @mrg95 As I point out in my answer, better use `QMetaObject::invokeMethod()` to avoid problems